# Sed command with exact variable change

Tags: linux, shell

I want to replace exact word by sed command with variable. My file looks like this:

```
//module xyz
module xyz
```

Suppose I have the following shell variables defined:

```
var1='module xyz'
var2='module abc'
```

I want to change xyz to abc in uncommented line only(module xyz)

So after executing command output should be

```
//module xyz    
module abc
```

I do not want to change commented line (//module xyz)

currently I am using sed command as,

```
sed -i "s|$var1|$var2|g" file_name
```

But this command doesn't work. It also replace commented line. How can I only replace the line that isn't commented?

Comment: `var1=module xyz` assings `module` to `var1` and runs `xyz`.

Comment: @choroba my fault, I edited that part, will fix.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the pattern is at the start of the line, you can use this:

```
sed "s|^$var1|$var2|" file_name
```

That is, add an anchor `^`, so that the match has to be at the start of the line.

I removed the `-i` switch so you can test it and also the `g` modifier, which isn't necessary as you only want to do one substitution per line.

It's worth mentioning that using shell variables in sed is actually [quite tricky to do in a reliable way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/2088135), so you should take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

- Your shell variable assignment should be quoted if there is space. Like:

  ```
  var1="foo bar blah"
  ```
- You can add pattern, "the lines don't start with // " to your sed command, so that do your substitution only for those lines

This line should work for your example:

```
sed -i "\@^//@\!s/$var1/$var2/g" file
```

- the `!` needs to be escaped, because we used double quote
- since your pattern (comment) has slash (`/`), I used other char as regex separator
- This command will only do substitution on lines not starting with `//`. If there are leading spaces, you may want to adjust the pattern `^//`

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify a pattern so that lines containing that pattern should not be processed.
Assuming that `//` will exist only in commented lines you can use

`sed -i '/\/\// !s/$var1/$var2/g' file_name`

`/\/\//` will enable sed to identify lines which contain the pattern `//`, and `!s` will enable you to skip those lines.